During testing time Thunder Client shows fake result for Authorization vs Bearer with same token
I am using Thunder Client for testing jwt token
After login, Token generated successfully,

Headers- Authorization- generated token
I got error message
{
  "message": "Invalid token"
}


But
Auth- Bearer- Bearer Token- generated token
I got successfully message
{
  "message": "I am a private route"
}


So what is the problem with the Authorization vs Bearer token?

You have to use bearer keyword followed by a space than token

its helpful, @Yuvaraj thanks

Because you are using bearer token when using that we have to set the Bearer keyword in Authorization header like below

That what automatically set's while using Auth->Bearer->Token
